# Make all other Divs dissapear javascript

Tags: javascript, html, show-hide

I got a Script Which makes me onclick showing all Divs with Specific id

This is the Selector

```
<a onclick="filterGal('simpleCart_shelfItem item Sonnenbrillen')" href="javascript:void(0);">Sonnenbrillen</a>
```

this is my Script

```
function filterGal(foo) {
                    var toHide = document.getElementsByClassName(foo);
                    for (i = 0; i < toHide.length; i++) {
                            toHide[i].style.display = 'block';
                    }
            }
```

So now my question how can i only show specific div with classname and display none the other div with other classnames?

Comment: [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) might be what you're looking for?

Comment: Why did you add the tag JQuery ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
function filterGal(foo) {
    var toHide = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
    for (i = 0; i < toHide.length; i++) {
         toHide[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
    var toShow = document.getElementsByClassName(foo);
    for (i = 0; i < toShow.length; i++) {
         toShow[i].style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

Can be improved by skiping in the first loop div which match your classes.

Comment: Not working he shows none div then ... Any other Idea?

Comment: Try again I made a mistake

Comment: Now he shows a blakn page complete Blank :( what could be the issue?

Comment: You valid the use of jquery ?

Comment: you mean include jquery ?

Comment: could you help me please

Answer (score 0):

I just show you add jquery tag so you just need to do this :

```
function filterGal(foo) {
    $( "div:not("+foo+")" ).hide();
}
```

Exemple : http://jsfiddle.net/ACjeZ/1

Comment: Did you try my jsfiddle link ? Please note that I pass classes with a `.` before. Not `foo` but `.foo`. @user1607143

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would try:

```
$("div").Hide();
$("." + foo).Show();
```